# How make pub build to use source maps on dart polymer projects

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

On a [dart polymer project](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/) when I do a debug [pub build](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-build.html) like so:

`pub build --mode debug`

the build process does correctly produce unminified javascript with [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) for the dart code.

However, the generated html file still references the .dart bootstrap script.

I can always manually modify the html after the fact to use the .js file, but that's a pain.

How do I get pub build to automatically generate an html file that references the debug javascript?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add a `js: true` entry for the polymer transformer in the pubspec file.

E.g.

```yml
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/polymer_example.html
    js: true
```

Comment: Did you find some explanation about what `js: true` is for? Or is this it's entire purpuse?

Comment: No, I stumbled across a usage of js: false in [a dartlang groups post](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/web-ui/jdoLc_roMLI/P1q8Cl3uBV0J). Turns out js:true works for what I need. But I'd love to have a link to the canonical set of options, with explanations.

Comment: Update: The dart polymer transfomer [source](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/pkg/polymer/lib/transformer.dart) is a good place to see all the options. Or, in the dart editor, \packages\polymer\transformer.dart.