# Dart to JS: How to debug the generated Javascript errors

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-pub, dart2js

Currently, the Javascript generated by dart2Js converter is very unintuitive to debug and doesn't produce intelligible error messages.

Is there a specific way that people use to debug Javascript code generated by dart?

I would like to get to the Dart line that is responsible for the error.

Also it would be great to see core dump and stack frames in terms of Dart code.

Comment: Seems there is ongoing work to support this eventually https://github.com/dart-lang/dev_compiler

Comment: The Javascript source maps solution is better. I want to see the Dart line that caused the error. And Dart stack frame.

I dont ever want to deal with Javascript (hopefully :P).

Answer (score 5):

At first ensure that you build with `pub build --mode=debug`.
This prevents minification and tree shaking.

Ensure that source maps are activated in Chrome devtools.
(DevTools settings - General - Sources - Enable JavaScript source maps).

Launch the application and debug.
The Chrome debugger should now show Dart source code when stepping through.

#### Polymer.dart

There seems to be an issue that the script used by default doesn't reference source maps [How make pub build to use source maps on dart polymer projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432500)

Comment: Thanks!!! I am not debugging for Chrome but for Firefox. Also, it would be great to see which dart line is responsible and see the stack frame with references to dart file and line numbers.

Comment: I don't know Firefox so well but it supports source maps too.